# Getting a feed of all questions that contain a certain word

Tags: support, feed

I'm managing an open-source project called [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org). I want to have a feed of all questions or answers containing the word "GarlicSim" so I could monitor this feed every day on my feed reader. This is so I could immediately answer any time someone asks a question about my project.

How can I do that? I know how to get a feed of the tag "GarlicSim" but I don't want it as a tag, I want it as a search word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) for that.